# Preservation of multiline yaml string in exact format when opening file

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm developing an app where I preserve the response of an api call in a yaml file and then as a second part open that yaml file to access the response.

These are two independent runs so can't preserve the response in memory.

The response comes out as a string `"- dashboard: new_dashboard\n  title: New Dashboard\n  layout: newspaper\n  preferred_viewer: dashboards-next\n  description: this is my description\n  preferred_slug: altLyIglxfRs8N3WaNfTKQ\n  elements:\n  - name: ''\n    type: text\n    title_text: ''\n    body_text: '[{\"type\":\"h1\",\"children\":[{\"text\":\"jkjkjkjk\"}],\"align\":\"center\"}]'\n    rich_content_json: '{\"format\":\"slate\"}'\n    row: 0\n    col: 0\n    width: 8\n    height: 6\n  - title: Untitled\n    name: Untitled\n    model: system__activity\n    explore: history\n    type: table\n    fields: [history.created_day_of_week, user_query_rank.user_name, history.query_run_count]\n    pivots: [user_query_rank.user_name]\n    filters:\n      history.created_date: 7 days\n    sorts: [user_query_rank.user_name desc]\n    column_limit: 50\n    listen: {}\n    row: 0\n    col: 8\n    width: 8\n    height: 6\n"`

However when I access it, the packages i'm using (pyyaml, ruamel yaml and json) seems to be adding on a series of escape characters to empty strings, so for instance `- name: ''\` this turns into `- name: \'\'\` Causing issues.

I've tried pyYaml, ruamel.yaml and persisting in json files. I'm not wedded to the file type, just in preserving the integrity of the string.

The goal is to have the response preserved in a text file and then be able to open that text file and have the response unchanged. Is there another format i'm missing or a different way to think about this problem?

Thanks

Comment: it seems like it's specifically the difference between escaping `'` and `"`, is there anyway to switch these ?

Comment: Why do you serialize a string that contains YAML? Why not write the string to the YAML file directly? And why does `\'\'` cause problems? In a YAML double-quoted string, it has the same semantics as `''` so it should be fine. You should edit your question to contain a minimal verifyable example including a description of the error you're running into.